# What is wrong with this alternative bitwise operator function?

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

```
n1 = "0b1110"
n2 = "0b101"

def bitwise_or(num1, num2):
    diff1 = ""
    new_num1 = []
    new_num2 = []
    new_num = []
    for c in num1:
        new_num1.append(c)
    for c in num2:
        new_num2.append(c)
    if len(num1) != len(num2):
        if len(num1) > len(num2):
            diff1 = "0" * (len(num1) - len(num2))
            for c in diff1:
                new_num2.append(c)
        if len(num1) < len(num2):
            diff1 = "0" * (len(num2) - len(num1))
            for c in diff1:
                new_num1.append(c)
    for i in range(len(new_num1)):
        if new_num1[i] == "1" or new_num2[i] == "1":
            new_num.append("1")
        else:
            new_num.append(new_num1[i])
    final = "".join(new_num)
    return final

print(bitwise_or(n1,n2))
```

I made a function that should replicate the | operation, however it's not working correctly. The correct answer was suppose to print out 0b1111, but I don't understand how it gets that.

Comment: Have you accounted for the "0b" prefix?

Comment: When you pass in `0b10000001` and `0b1` you add `0` to the second one at the end, so you end up doing the or of `0b10000001` and `0b10000000` but python's `|` operator would actually consider the second one as `0b00000001`.

Comment: @jtbandes That's not the problem. Since `b` is different from `1` the `b` fails the test in the if and gets inserted in `new_num`.

Comment: You're also zero-padding incorrectly.  The zeros need to go on the left side of the strings, not the right.  Any why are you looping to do it?  You already have the full-width zero string, and a simple `+` operator will perform string concatenation.  Plus, do you really want this function to operate on strings rather than integers?

Comment: The `0b` prefixes most certainly need to be discarded.  The zero-padding problem can't be fixed properly until this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pad the zeros you should insert them *before* the bits of the number.

`0b1` means the number `1`. If you try to or it with `0b11101` you cannot change it to `0b10000` you have to pad it as `0b00001`.

Also your handling of `0b` works but isn't clear not readable. It just "happen" to work because when you loop through `0b11101` and `0b00001` the first character is `0` in both and so you end up in `new_num.append(new_num1[0])` and then `b != '1'` and hence the `if` test fails and the `b` gets inserted in `new_num`.

I suggest you simply remove the prefix at the beginning and add it at the end. This also slightly simplifies correct padding.

---

By the way: to convert a string to a list of characters you can simply call `list` on it:

```
new_num1 = list(num1)
```

Moreover to add a certain number of elements to a list you can use the `extend` method, or you could use slice assignment:

```
>>> my_list = list('hello')
>>> my_list
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> my_list.extend('world')
>>> my_list
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

So your code would become somewhat like this:

```
def bitwise_or(num1, num2):
    new_num1 =list(num1)
    new_num2 = list(num2)
    if len(num1) > len(num2):
        new_num2[2:2] = '0' * (len(num1) - len(num2))
    elif len(num1) < len(num2):
        new_num1[2:2] = '0' * (len(num2) - len(num1))

    new_num = []
    for c1, c2 in zip(new_num1, new_num2):
        if c1 == "1" or c2 == "1":
            new_num.append("1")
        else:
            new_num.append(c1)
    return ''.join(new_num)
```

However I'd rather make explicit the handling of the prefix:

```
def bitwise_or(num1, num2):
    new_num1 =list(num1[2:])
    new_num2 = list(num2[2:])
    if len(num1) > len(num2):
        new_num2[:0] = '0' * (len(num1) - len(num2))
    elif len(num1) < len(num2):
        new_num1[:0] = '0' * (len(num2) - len(num1))

    new_num = []
    for c1, c2 in zip(new_num1, new_num2):
        if c1 == "1" or c2 == "1":
            new_num.append("1")
        else:
            new_num.append(c1)
    return '0b' + ''.join(new_num)
```

Comment: How would I add it at the beginning instead of the end?

Comment: @XTImpossible Look at the end of my answer (note I've fixed a slight bug right now). The `list` type doesn't have a specific method for doing that, however you can use slice assignment. For example `my_list[2:2] = [1,2,3]` will add the elements `1`, `2` and `3` at index `2` without removing any elements and `my_list[:0] = [1,2,3]` prepends the elements `1`, `2` and `3` to the list.  Alternatively you can use the `insert` function and do `my_list.insert(0, 3); my_list.insert(0, 2); my_list.insert(0, 1)`

Comment: @XTImpossible If you have to prepend stuff often you may consider using a different data type such as `deque` which has operations like `appendleft`/`extendleft` which add stuff at the beginning.

Comment: Alright, I'll keep that in mind. Although, this will be the last question I post, because I have too many disliked posts. Got banned :/

Comment: @XTImpossible Bans have a time limit. Just look back at your post and try to understand why they were badly received and when you getn unbanned try to avoid those mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

The method you are following is a bit complex, however the error in your code is that you right-pad with zeros in case of different lenght. In the given case you get the 0b101 become a 0b1010, which ORed with 0b1110 gives the result you end up with. You shall left-pad binary numbers, that is 0b101 shall become 0b0101. This code works

```
n1 = "0b1110"
n2 = "0b101"

def bitwise_or(num1, num2):
    new_num1 = []
    new_num2 = []
    new_num = []

    for c in num1[2:]:
        new_num1.append(c)

    for c in num2[2:]:
        new_num2.append(c)

    if len(num1) != len(num2):
        if len(num1) > len(num2):
            diff1 = ["0"] * (len(num1) - len(num2))
            new_num2 = diff1 + new_num2
        if len(num1) < len(num2):
            diff1 = ["0"] * (len(num2) - len(num1))
            new_num1 = diff1 + new_num1
    for i in range(len(new_num1)):
        if new_num1[i] == "1" or new_num2[i] == "1":
            new_num.append("1")
        else:
            new_num.append(new_num1[i])
    final = "".join(new_num)
    return final


print(bitwise_or(n1, n2))
```

I'd suggest to convert your binary numbers (skipping the '0b' prefix) into lists of integers and the apply the OR logical operator bit by bit. You may also give a try to list comprehensions, for example

```
new_num1 = [int(i) for i in n1[2:]]
```

and to external functions (which you may also define inside another function, such as the one that left pads the shorter number.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my optimized version. One does not necessarily have to do it like this, but see it as inspiration to explore Python's features. It can handle any number of input parameters btw, but probably (?) works on Python 3 only though...

```
def format_binary_string(bin_string, length, prefix=""):
    return "{}{:0{}b}".format(prefix, int(bin_string, 2), length)

def bitwise_or(*numbers):
    max_length = max(len(n) for n in numbers)
    bits = [format_binary_string(n, max_length, "") for n in numbers]

    new_bits = ["1" if "1" in bs else "0" for bs in zip(*bits)]
    return "".join(new_bits)


n1 = "0b1110"
n2 =  "0b101"
print(bitwise_or(n1, n2))
```